# How to clean a .log file at the end of each day that was created with logger_file_backend?

Tags: logging, elixir

I have used a `logger_file_backend` backend in order to create a `.log` file that holds all messages from given level.

Example of a config:

```
config :logger, :mapping_metadata_error,
  format: "$time $metadata[$level] $message\n",
  path: "log/mappings/metadata_error.log",
  level: :error,
  metadata_filter: [mapping: :metadata_error]
```

I would like to clean this file `metadata_error.log` at the end of the day so it does not become super long.

I am not sure how to achieve this goal. I was reading about `:compile_time_purge_matching`, however I am not sure how to use it after reading documentation and if that's what I need.

I will be grateful for help.

Comment: Would not [`truncate`](https://linuxhint.com/truncate-command-in-linux/) run by `cron` and/or [`logrotate`](https://linuxconfig.org/logrotate) suffice?

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, I think! Thank you so much! You are the best